# How to create custom rule in fxcop

Tags: c#, .net, fxcop, fxcop-customrules

Can you please tell me the step by step explanation about how to create custom rules using FXCop for .Net. In FxCop, what value we input we need to choose for Target and What input we need to choose for Rules?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: This sounds like you haven't even googled the basic info, please do that before asking questions here on [SO]. See this blog by a c# MVP: http://blog.tatham.oddie.com.au/2010/01/06/custom-code-analysis-rules-in-vs2010-and-how-to-make-them-run-in-fxcop-and-vs2008-too/

Comment: I searched so many websites. But I couldn't see what input we need to give in target and custom rules section.

Comment: Cool, I hope that link answers your question. Cheers:)